# Big O notation property

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Does the following correct and why?

$O(1)+O(\sqrt{n})=O(\sqrt{n})$,

where $O(.)$ means big O notation.

My thinking is that it is correct because
$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0 < \infty$. Thus  $1\leq \sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

One should follow the formal [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) of the big O notation.

Let $f,g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ be two sequences such that for some constant $C,M>0$, for every $n>M$,
$$
|f(n)|\le C,\quad |g(n)|\le C\sqrt{n} 
$$

By the triangle inequality,
$$
|f(n)+g(n)|\leq C(1+\sqrt{n})\leq 2C\sqrt{n}
$$

So $f+g\in O(\sqrt{n})$.

On the other hand, if $f\in O(\sqrt{n})$, it is trivial to see that $f\in O(1)+O(\sqrt{n})$.

Answer (score -1):

Your equation basically means a bounded function, say f, plus an another bounded function g times $\sqrt{n}$
so $\frac{f(n)+g(n)\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ is still bounded (as n tends to infinity), and yes, it's correct.

Comment: How so?  Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).